# How to push an object inside the nested object?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I get `longDesc` from a second AJAX call and I'd like to merge it with the first call.

My code:

```
transform: {
    fn(data) {
        const longDesc = [];
        Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: `url`,
        method: 'GET',
        scope: this,
        success(response) {
            const dataSet = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
            Ext.each(dataSet.data, value => {
            longDesc.push(value.longDesc);
            });
        },
        failure() {},
        });
        data.data.longDesc = longDesc;              
        return data;
},
```

I get this log:

[image]

but I'd like to move `longDesc` inside each data object

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the longDesc array in each element in data and not attach it directly to data.I think this is what you are trying to achieve-

```
transform: {
    fn(data) {
        const longDesc = [];
        Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: `url`,
        method: 'GET',
        scope: this,
        success(response) {
            const dataSet = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
            Ext.each(dataSet.data, value => {
            longDesc.push(value.longDesc);
            });
        },
        failure() {},
        });
        data.data.forEach(function(entry) {
         entrylongDesc = longDesc;
        });
        return data;
},
```

Comment: This almost answers my question. I just need to move it under the success loop but it's not binding the values correctly.

Comment: @Grasper moving it to success loop won't work as in the success loop you are creating the longDesc array. you would need to do the assignment after the longDesc array is created from response. hence the extra foreach later on.

Comment: I did move it and it does work! I just needed to add an if statement to avoid wrong association.